# Angular2 Zone.js not working

Tags: javascript, angular

Sometimes Zone.js is not updating/deploying my typescript classes. It really gets me nuts. Usually it works just fine, but sometimes it simply ignores my modifications. Could it be because of my bad laptop? I also recently updated from RC2-3 to RC5. It is strange especially because it usually works just fine.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is this a zone.js bug? Is this because maybe I configured the project badly or just because of my low performance laptop?

Comment: Zone.JS is a zone for javascript, same as what we have in Dart. how it is related to code deploying or laptop performance. what do you mean by not updating typescript classes?